# Controlling Virtualized CPU's Clock Speed?

Tags: c, throttling, vm-implementation

I'm currently building a small virtual machine in c modelling an old 16-bit CPU, which runs at a super slow clock speed (a few 100 Khz). How would I throttle the virtual machine's processing speed of opcode, etc..? or would I even want to?

Comment: if youre virtualizing couldnt you just run each opcode after a certain amount of time? or do you mean literally slow down the rate that the vm youre writing has opcodes interpreted by your physical processor?

Comment: @DanZimm The later one, though the first could be a somewhat hacky solution. Each opcode is supposed to take so many "cpu cycles", though not true cycles, I'd have to emulate my own.

Comment: well what about the fact that as you parse the opcodes, multiple cpu cycles will occur per virtual opcode? in other words would it not be better to just use a timer or something if you desire it to be slower down? you could even use sleep()

Comment: @DanZimm That could work, but how would I match a specific Khz? Not exactly how seconds, or milliseconds would transfer to Khz?

Comment: ... Not exactly sure* ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments I suggest using some sort of timer mechanism

if you would like to match a certain speed here is how I would do it:

```
1 kHz   1000 Hz    1/s             
----- * ------- * ----- therefore  1 kHz = 1000/s
  1      1 kHz     1 Hz
```

which means every second 1000 operations are occurring, so take the reciprocal to find the amount of time in between operations so 1/1000 s or 1 ms

So lets say you want to match 125 kHz

```
125 kHz   1000 Hz    1/s             
------- * ------- * ----- therefore  125 kHz = 125000/s
  1      1 kHz       1 Hz
```

so 1/125000 s or .008 ms or 8000 ns

Hope this helps!