# Virtualize specific environment (CPU, cache, clock)

Tags: virtual-machine, simulation, virtualization

I have written some code that's supposed to run on a certain hardware-setup. I'd like to test it to get some preliminary metrics, but without buying the hardware setup, since it's very expensive.

At first I, naively, thought I could set some specifications to the platform when creating a virtual machine through a manager such as VMware Workstation, but it seems like it's not possible.
What ways do you believe would be the best to emulate a certain environment? Of course, RAM, disk space and OS should be fairly easy, but limiting the CPU seems to be the general issue. 
I'm trying to simulate the Intel Atom® Processor E3845, so I have some requirements to the maximum cores, cache size and of course the clock frequency.

The closest I've found so far would be to install WMware ESXi on a piece of hardware and limit the CPU. But I'm unsure if this is the best way. Further, I've never really worked with this before, why I'm unsure if I can limit the cache and so forth. Simply ["down-scaling" the metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968236/controlling-virtualized-cpus-clock-speed) does not feel like a good solution when we are rather dependant on the cache (that is, we've seen issues with certain sizes and speeds).

I Would love to hear some inputs if you have any.

Comment: There are more problems, E665CT has limited IPC and no out-of-order execution, which makes it much weaker clock-for-clock than the high performance processors, even if the cache was the same size.

Comment: @harold thanks! I see that I posted the wrong CPU, it's updated to E3845. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: It does a bit, E3845 has some out-of-order capabilities, but it's very limited and IPC is still low